# Filedrop.js no success Message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli, filedrop.js

i am using filedrop.js fo an Image Upload Script.
I fund a script here : https://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php

In the Prject is a file_post.php which i wanted to change to save some informations (like the Filename) into a Database.

This is my post_file.php :

```
    <?php

// If you want to ignore the uploaded files, 
// set $demo_mode to true;

$demo_mode = false;
$upload_dir = 'uploads/tmp/';
$allowed_ext = array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');


if(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) != 'post'){
    exit_status('Error! Wrong HTTP method!');
}


if(array_key_exists('pic',$_FILES) && $_FILES['pic']['error'] == 0 ){

    $pic = $_FILES['pic'];

    if(!in_array(get_extension($pic['name']),$allowed_ext)){
        exit_status('Only '.implode(',',$allowed_ext).' files are allowed!');
    }   

    if($demo_mode){

        // File uploads are ignored. We only log them.

        $line = implode('       ', array( date('r'), $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $pic['size'], $pic['name']));
        file_put_contents('log.txt', $line.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

        exit_status('Uploads are ignored in demo mode.');
    }


    // Move the uploaded file from the temporary 
    // directory to the uploads folder:

    if(move_uploaded_file($pic['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.$pic['name'])){

        //My added code
```

include('/var/www/html/board/SSI.php');

```
$userName = $context['user']['name'];
$content_id = $_COOKIE["contentid"];
$pic_name = $pic['name'];
$pic_code = $content_id;
$pic_path = $pic_name;


$db_host = "******";
$db_name = "******";
$db_user = "******";
$db_pass = "******";

$db = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_user","$db_pass","$db_name") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($db));

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `User_pics` (content_id, path, user_id,  user_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $pic_code,
$pic_path,
$context['user']['id'],
$context['user']['name']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

        //end of my added code





        exit_status('File was uploaded successfuly!');
    }

}

exit_status('Something went wrong with your upload!');


// Helper functions

function exit_status($str){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>$str));
    exit;
}

function get_extension($file_name){
    $ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $ext = array_pop($ext);
    return strtolower($ext);
}
?>
```

After i added the mysqli part the Success message is not shown anymore.
On the Image Upload the Progressbar stops at about 50%. The files are Uploaded and the informations are ssaved into the DB, but i got no success respons and this i need to handle the next steps. pleas help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for interrests,
two days i worked fo a soulution, after i asked here i found the Answer ;)

The Problem was the Include of the SSI.php which is encoded in UTF-8.
This was the reason for an Error in the Json encoded Response.

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

My soulution was:
I created a cookie for User ID and User name so i was able to remove the Include. After this every thing works great. If someone has the Same Error simply create a cookie where you are showing your Upload Form, after Upload delet them.

Thanks to the Community and have a nice Day ;)